# How to understand netezza modified query?

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I have the following query extracted from a netezza view, Since there is no record of original query saved. How to understand what this query is doing?

```
CASE 
    WHEN (O.E_SRC ~~LIKE_ESCAPE('FIX.%.OrderNew'::"VARCHAR", '\'::"VARCHAR"))
    THEN ADMIN."REPLACE"(ADMIN."REPLACE"(O.E_SRC, '.OrderNew'::"VARCHAR", ''::"VARCHAR"),
                        'FIX.'::"VARCHAR", ''::"VARCHAR")
    ELSE O.E_SRC
END AS CONNECTION_ID
```

What I understood is, there is a pattern matching on `FIX.%.OrderNew` and it does some kind of replace. So what would be the original query saves?
Like `NVL(RNO,0)` is saved as

```
CASE 
    WHEN (RNO NOTNULL) THEN RNO
    WHEN (0 NOTNULL) THEN 0
    ELSE NULL::INT4
END
```

So what is the original query equivalent to `nvl()` or some other function of the following netezza modified query

```
CASE 
    WHEN (O.E_SRC ~~LIKE_ESCAPE('FIX.%.OrderNew'::"VARCHAR", '\'::"VARCHAR"))
    THEN ADMIN."REPLACE"(ADMIN."REPLACE"(O.E_SRC, '.OrderNew'::"VARCHAR", ''::"VARCHAR"),
                         'FIX.'::"VARCHAR", ''::"VARCHAR")
    ELSE O.E_SRC
END AS CONNECTION_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VIEW is obfucscating the original code, but not too badly.

If we start with a table like this:

```
 select * from so_table;

 COL1     E_SRC              
 -------  ------------------ 
 1        FIX.SCOTT.OrderNew 
 2        BREAK.BOB.OrderOld
```

And create a view like this:

```
create or replace view so_view as
select
case 
    when o.e_src like('FIX.%.OrderNew')
    then replace(
        replace(o.e_src, '.OrderNew','')
            ,'FIX.','')
    ELSE o.e_src
END as CONNECTION_ID
from so_table o ;
```

We can then check the view source as it's stored in the catalog:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (O.E_SRC ~~ LIKE_ESCAPE('FIX.%.OrderNew'::"VARCHAR", '\'::
        "VARCHAR")) THEN ADMIN."REPLACE"(ADMIN."REPLACE"(O.E_SRC,
        '.OrderNew'::"VARCHAR",
        ''::"VARCHAR"),
        'FIX.'::"VARCHAR",
        ''::"VARCHAR") ELSE O.E_SRC END AS CONNECTION_ID 
FROM
    ADMIN.SO_TABLE O;
```

From this you can see that it's converting LIKE (with the implied '\' escape character) to a different form, as well as tacking on typecasts to each expression.

```
select * from so_view;

 CONNECTION_ID      
 ------------------ 
 BREAK.BOB.OrderOld 
 SCOTT
```

In this case, it's pulling the middle substring out of a string that starts with 'FIX.' and ends with '.OrderNew', otherwise it just returns the original string.

Comment: You are genius man.. Thanks a lot!!! Does it come from experience or there is any particular way to understand it?

Comment: Mostly just experience. The thing to keep in mind is that whatever is stored in the view definition is supposed to equivalent to what was used with the CREATE VIEW statement.  For the most part this means cosmetic changes (like the :: casting of expressions), but can be bigger (like the change of the simpler LIKE to the more complicated, but still equivalent, LIKE_ESCAPE.  Glad I could help!